# Getting arguments from the stack in c

Tags: c

I just started to learn c and I was trying to create a function that gets it's arguments from the stack when I know all the arguments are from the same type, but it worked only for int.

This is what I did:

```
void Test1(double first_arg, ...)
{
    double *a = &first_arg;
    printf("arg[0]: %f\narg[1]: %f \narg[2]: %f\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
void Test2(int first_arg, ...)
{
    int *a = &first_arg;
    printf("arg[0]: %d\narg[1]: %d \narg[2]: %d\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
}
int main()
{
    printf("Test1:\n");
    Test1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    printf("\nTest2:\n");
    Test2(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}

Console:
Test1:
arg[0]: 1.000000
arg[1]: 0.000000
arg[2]: 0.000000

Test2:
arg[0]: 1
arg[1]: 2
arg[2]: 3
```

What am I missing here? And what should I do to fix this.

Comment: The stack? This is called a variadic function. I would guess this is undefined behavior. Check out the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Functions.html) to see how to properly use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way arguments are passed to a function are implementation dependent.  To read variable arguments in a portable way, you need to use the `stdarg` family of functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void Test1(double first_arg, ...)
{
    printf("arg[0]=%f\n", first_arg);

    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, first_arg);
    double arg1 = va_arg(ap, double);
    printf("arg[1]=%f\n", arg1);
    double arg2 = va_arg(ap, double);
    printf("arg[2]=%f\n", arg2);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Test1:\n");
    Test1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without stdarg? I'm more interested in how it's working.

Comment: @TᴏᴍᴇʀWᴏʟʙᴇʀɢ You'll need to dig into your specific compiler internals to see how it works.  While integer arguments tend to be passed on the stack, floating point arguments tend to be passed via floating point registers.  You would need to write some assembly to do what you want.